# Any reason to send a user a session salt?

Tags: network, salt, json

I'm a summer intern turned full time employee. To make a long story short, the lead developer of the project I interned on quit, and since I'm the only other person that knows the project I got hired full time to maintain it.

Anyway, while poking around the program, I found that - upon loading a specific admin tool - the server sends the client a JSON packet containing:

[image: Blacked out, because infosec]

### My question: *What possible reason could there be to send the client a session salt?*

My security background is watching a few Defcon talks to kill time, so I'm no professional, but from what I know salts and hashes are something you're supposed to guard with your life. I also know that anything sent over a network is fundamentally unsecured. Furthermore, the only place this salt is used clientside is a text-field on that admin tool that simply displays the salt.

So what reason is there for this to be sent to the user? Should I edit the server so it doesn't send the salt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If implementing custom session handling, salt obviously shouldn't be passed to the client, it should be stored either in a configuration file or in a database. Only the session token should be transferred between the client and the server.

First of all I'd suggest to look for uses of `SESSION_SALT`. If it's not used, remove it as you are just leaking sensitive information here. If you find something, we can take a closer look of what it's meant to do. My first thought was that the programmer just used wrong terminology here and it's actually a session token.

Comment: I poked around, and the only place that the salt gets used is in a display field. Leftover debug function, I guess?

Comment: Yes, most likely.